# Model.ManyToManyField.all() gives AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror, manytomanyfield, django-2.0

I'm using Django 2.0.2, Python 3.6.4 and PyCharm 2017.3.3

Models: (in models.py)

```
class Position(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gang = models.ForeignKey(Gang, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=20000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title) + ', ' + str(self.gang)

class Application(models.Model):
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position)
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Ranking(models.Model):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=3,validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(3),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ])
```

Form: (in forms.py)

```
class RankingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    rank = forms.IntegerField(max_value=3, min_value=1)
    position = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Application.positions.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Ranking
        exclude = ['applicant']
        fields = ('rank', 'position')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RankingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['rank'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

I keep getting the AttributeError in RankingForm from

"position = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Application.positions.all())"

When i write

```
class Application(models.Model):
    ... 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.positions.all())
```

it shows in django-admin as a QuerySet (which works for forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField()), but writing

```
    class Application(models.Model):
    ... 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(Application.positions.all())
```

gives me the same error: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Writing

```
    class RankingForm(forms.ModelForm):
        ...
        position = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Position.objects.all())
```

works, but this is not what i want the field to display.

I want to make a ModelMultipleChoiceField() with all the  positions from a specific application, but this error keeps getting in the way. It seems that just referencing a model doesn't work, but referencing self does?? Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Btw, I haven't found any good documentation on this problem, but [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py/%22here%22) seems to be the code for related_descriptors.py where ManyToManyDescriptor is located

Comment: Your question is confusing. You know the working syntax, using self, so why are you trying to use the other version?

Comment: You need an instance of the application and can't used the property of a class that isn't initialized.

Comment: You should have `self.positions.all()` not `Application.positions.all()` `self` references an instance of the application. For the form the querset should be evaluated at initialization not at class level i.e `position = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Positions.objects.none())`

Comment: @DanielRoseman what do you mean by "the other version"?

Comment: @jackotonye Yes, I want to reference the application instance, but how do I do that when I'm in forms.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating relationships are done with an instance that is an initialized instance of the class.

An instance of the Application.

```
application = Application.objects.first()
application.positions.all()
```

Change the form queryset after initialization.

```
class RankingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    rank = forms.IntegerField(max_value=3, min_value=1)
    position = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Positions.objects.none())

    class Meta:
        model = Ranking
        exclude = ['applicant']
        fields = ['rank', 'position']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RankingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['rank'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})  
        self.fields['position'].queryset = self.instance.positions.all()
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that I think about it, my question really only boiled down to "how to make a model instance" haha.

Comment: But I do need to make a model instance for the specific user viewing the form. Any help on that?

Comment: Instances are created once the user saves the form the edit view references the saved form instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current instance of your model that the `ModelForm` object is working with using the `instance` attribute. You can then use it to create the correct queryset in `__init__`:

```
class RankingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['rank'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['position'].queryset = self.instance.positions.all()
```