# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all' in django 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my forms.py:

```
class NewsletterCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Newsletter
        fields = ['subject', 'body', 'email', 'status']
```

this is my this is my newsletter models :

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Draft', 'Draft'),
        ('Published', 'Published')
    )
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
    body = models.TextField(default='')
    email = models.ManyToManyField(NewsletterUsers)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

and this is my views.py :

```
def control_newsletter_delet(request, pk):
    newsletter = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST, instance=Newsletter)

        if form.is_valid():
            newsletter.delete()
            return redirect('control_newsletter_list')

    else:
        form = NewsletterCreationForm(instance=newsletter)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'control_panel/control_newsletter_delete.html', context)
```

Now when I want to use my control_newsletter_delet() I face to this error :

```
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
```

I checked this link:
['ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481650/model-manytomanyfield-all-gives-attributeerror-manytomanydescriptor-object)
 and it cant help me to solve my problem.
is any body know why I get this error?
 **In addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Comment: this is my newsletter models, if some one need this :
`class Newsletter(models.Model):
    EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Draft', 'Draft'),
        ('Published', 'Published')
    )
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
    body = models.TextField(default='')
    email = models.ManyToManyField(NewsletterUsers)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject`

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Comment: I realized my problem.

Comment: You should construct a *new* `Newsletter` instance, so `Newsletter()` instead of `Newsletter` as instance.

Comment: Furthermore it is not really clear why you need a `Form` here anyway: you want to *delete* the object, and you have a primary key.

Comment: thanks, your right, I just can delete it directly without define form. I am new to django and when I search about how delete and edit and object with primary key, I just found this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happened because I passed extra parameter to `NewsletterCreationForm`.
to fix this problem just replcae `form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST, instance=Newsletter)` to `form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST or None)` and remove  instance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the form was *not* working with the `newsletter` instance, but with the `Newsletter` (with uppercase) class:

```
def control_newsletter_delet(request, pk):
    newsletter = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST, instance=newsletter)
        if form.is_valid():
            newsletter.delete()
            return redirect('control_newsletter_list')

    else:
        form = NewsletterCreationForm(instance=newsletter)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'control_panel/control_newsletter_delete.html', context)
```

But that being said, using a form here, does not make much sense: you want to *delete* a `Newsletter`, and the `pk` already determines what the newsletter is, so a we can omit the form. Especially since it is a "creation" form:

```
def control_newsletter_delet(request, pk):
    newsletter = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newsletter.delete()
        return redirect('control_newsletter_list')

    form = NewsletterCreationForm(instance=newsletter)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'control_panel/control_newsletter_delete.html', context)
```

Probably the `form` can be omitted completely.

Comment: I have another problem too, when I delete an object, its delete successfully but I'm not redirect to `control_newsletter_list`. Do you know I redirect isn't work?

Comment: How do you call this function? With a `<form>` submit? An AJAX call? Can you see anything in the Network inspector of the browser, or the console of the Django server?

Comment: you mean this : 
`{% for item in items %}
<tr><td><a href="{% url 'control_newsletter_edit' pk=item.pk %}">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'control_newsletter_delete' pk=item.pk %}">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}` ?

Comment: But here you use a `<a href=...>` so you make a GET request, instead of a POST. As a result the `if method == 'POST'` body will never get evaluated.

Comment: so if I put them in <form method="post'> it will be work?

Comment: @Ali: if you *submit* the form yes, so not with an `<a href=...>` but with a `<input type="submit" value="Delete">`, but in such cases, it is better to make AJAX requests.

Comment: I dont know much about AJAX, so if you want to use Ajax how should I use it?
can you guide me?

Comment: @Ali: it is making requests with JavaScript, see here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp